# Packaging python app with entry point: command script in the entry point not executed after wheel installation with pip install

Tags: python, python-packaging

I have tried to package my python script using both `python -m build` and `python -m setup.py`. In both cases, the wheel is generated, but after install the one generated by `python -m build` with `python -m pip install`, the command line defined in the entry point is not available, while after installing the package with `python -m setup.py install`, the command is available.
I decided to use `python -m build` because using setuptools I get a SetuptoolsDeprecation warning. But unfortunately, it is not working as expected. What is the best practice to create and install python wheels in order to have the entry points working from the command line directly ?

Im using python 3.9.12 in a conda env in linux.

this is the setup.py

```py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

entry_point = (
    "command = package_name.module:main_func"
)

# get the dependencies and installs
with open("requirements.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    requires = []
    for line in f:
        req = line.split("#", 1)[0].strip()
        requires.append(req)

setup(
    name="package_name",
    version="0.1",
    description="description",
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points={"console_scripts": [entry_point]},
    install_requires=requires,
    python_requires=">=3.6",
    extras_require={},
)
```

Thanks!